# I bought bitcoin from an ATM machine but the person I want to send it to didn't not see it

Tags: bitcoin-atm

[image] this is the receipt I got but the address on it is different from the address I want to sent it to

Answer (score 1):

Both of the transactions are confirmed and can be viewed using a block explorer. Furthermore, both of them were spent by your friend 6 hours ago.

[Transaction 1](https://blockstream.info/tx/4fe18557d2b4e38c08dea0435e80bd58bbae48ce1621834a36ea09c17a0c9e2b)
[Transaction 2](https://blockstream.info/tx/16e4f59d9dca69cf5420466b7703e3dcb83fe9a43362abbfb3d6dc1cc363325b)

In other words, those transactions have been seen by them and spent.